# $http.post URL is getting trimmed off if URL has "#"

Tags: angularjs, rest, http-post

I'm having one Rest API: `/myApp/fetchData/User-Name/Password`. User-Name and Password will be changed based on the request.

When i call the above restapi like this

```
/myApp/fetchData/srikanth/Abcdef#g123
```

the request is going like this:

```
/myApp/fetchData/srikanth/Abcdef
```

Basically in the URL text got removed from `#` character. Is there any way to solve?

Thanks,
Srikanth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a URI the `#` triggers the begins of the ["fragment"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#URI_references), and ends the path. The fragment usually specify a portion of the resource identified by the path.

When you are post-ing the request from the client, you have to [escape special characters](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp). Your request should be:

```
/myApp/fetchData/srikanth/Abcdef%23g123
```

There are different way to escaping urls, like the [`encodeURI`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp) or [`encodeURIComponent`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp) function in JS. For example, you may do:

```
var request = "/myApp/fetchData/srikanth/" + encodeURIComponent("Abcdef#g123");
```

Then the server have to decode back to the original request.

But: are you sure it is a good solution to send the password plain in that way?